# How to identify a function with just one line of code using python

Tags: python, parsing

My goal is to identify methods/ functions that are one lines. For example in scenario.py there are two function that has only one line of code written within them. My works is that i have a large application and I will be parsing all the python files in that application and identify function that has one lines.

```
#Scenario.py
line 1--->  class parent:
line 2--->     def father(self):
line 3--->        print "dad"
line 4--->     def mother(self):
line 5--->        print "mom"

Sample Output:

One liner function at : line=2, line =4
```

Comment: Just curious, what is this needed for? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: Actually i am instrumenting decorators on to the functions that has more than one line and retrieve some dynamic information during runtime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html):

```
import ast

def iter_functions(code):
    tree = ast.parse(code)
    for x in tree.body:
        if isinstance(x, ast.FunctionDef):
            yield x
        elif isinstance(x, ast.ClassDef):
            for x in tree.body:
                for y in x.body:
                    yield y

code = r'''class parent:
    def father(self):
        print "dad"
    def mother(self):
        print "mom"
    def grandfather(self):
        print "grand"
        print "dad"
'''

# This is incorrect. See UPDATE
for f in iter_functions(code):
    if len(f.body) > 0 and len({stmt.lineno for stmt in f.body}) == 1:
        print(f.lineno)
```

prints

```
2
4
```

**NOTE**

If there is a syntax error in the code, this code will raise `SyntaxError`. Also, if you try to parse *Python 3* code with *Python 2* (vice versa), it could raise `SyntaxError` (not always).

### UPDATE

Above `for` statement should be replaced with following:

```
for f in iter_functions(code):
    if len({node.lineno for stmt in f.body for node in ast.walk(stmt)
            if hasattr(node, 'lineno')}) == 1:
        print(f.lineno)
```

Otherwise, following function is considered as oneliner:

```
def func():
    if True:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that works with "live" Python functions. Note that this is very CPython-specific.

```
def func(x):
    print(x)

def numlines(func):
    lnotab = bytearray(func.__code__.co_lnotab)
    return sum(lnotab[3::2]) + (bool(lnotab) and min(lnotab[1], 1))

print(numlines(func) < 2)    # True
```

This ignores docstrings and counts only the body of the function. Functions that define the body on the same line as the `def` (or are `lambda`) are considered to have 0 lines.

A version that doesn't ignore docstrings is a bit simpler:

```
def numlines_including_docstring(func):
    return sum(bytearray(func.__code__.co_lnotab)[1::2])
```

My original code was badly broken; it counted statements rather than lines. In my defense, I wrote it off the top of my head and misremembered details about `lnotab`.

Note that in Python 3 the conversion to `bytearray` is not necessary (since `co_lnotab` is already `bytes`) but doing so makes the code work with both Python 2.x, where `co_lnotab` is a `str` (I *think* 2.6 and later have `__code__`) and 3.x.

Comment: If the body of `func(x)` of is `if True: pass` (2 lines), `oneliner` returns `True`.

Comment: Yep yep. Screwed that up. Have hopefully fixed it now. I removed the `oneliner()` function since it's easy enough to just test `numlines(func)`.

Answer (score -1):

Using inspect and regex:

```
import re
import inspect
import my_module

for name, func in inspect.getmembers(my_module, predicate=inspect.isfunction):
    func_source = inspect.getsource(func)
    nlines = len(re.findall('\n', func_source))
    print (name, nlines)
```

Comment: `myfunc` is not defined. Maybe it's `func`. You should unpack `func` into `name, func`. And, this code only handle module level function (not method).